# unetbootin: cannot mount squashfs on loop device

Tags: linux, loop-device, squashfs

Im having a bit of fun with unetbootin with linux mint 16 setup in it.

However when I try run the default menu item I get an error that ends with this:

can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs)

any ideas?

Comment: You might not need `unetbootin`  anymore. Using `dd if=your-image.iso of=/dev/sdi bs=4k`  where `your-image.iso`  is your CDROM image and `/dev/sdi` is your USB key is generally enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't loaded squashfs at all. Check with

```
grep squashfs /proc/filesystems
```

This problem is solved with

```
modprobe squashfs
```

Comment: hmm... something is wrong with unetbootin on win7 then :(

Comment: I see a file called filesystem.squashfs in the dir created by unetbootin